# Java 8 - Streams API - Operating on LIST

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have an ArrayList which contains the following - CHENNAI, MUMBAI, DELHI, CHENNAI, DELHI, CHENNAI. Also, assume that these 3 city names are defined as an ENUM with a value against each city. (CHENNAI=1, MUMBAI=2 AND DELHI=3)

My Java 8 Streams, I am able to compute the sum of city values which in this case would be 1+2+3+1+3+1 = 11.

Question I have is, how can I compute the sum of city values for the same ArrayList if there is an additional criteria which says,

if a city name appears twice, it must be added only once. i.e. in this case CHENNAI is present 3 times. So, when adding its value we should consider only 1 (for the first 2 occurrences) + 1  = 2 instead of 3. Similarly, DELHI is present 2 times. So, value of Delhi should be taken only once.
Hence the end result would be 2+2+3 = 7 instead of 11 as I explained before.

Please help how to to achieve this in Java 8

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Answer (score 7):

Map to your enum and use `.distinct()` to filter out duplicates before computing the sum.

Depending on how are you mapping the `enum` to `int` you can try:

```
List<String> cities = ...
int sum = cities.stream()
    .map(CityEnum::valueOf)
    .distinct()
    .mapToInt(CityEnum::ordinal)
    .sum();
```